# Log-in through authlogic without having to fill in form every time

Tags: cucumber, authlogic, capybara

I have a number of Cucumber scenarios which run with capybara on a project I am working on.

Most of these scenarios start with a "Given I am logged in" step. Currently my implementation of this is:

```
  visit path_to('the login page')
  fill_in('Username', :with => 'user')
  fill_in('Password', :with => 'password')
  click_button('Login')
```

This works fine, however it is becoming a bit time consuming having to load and submit the login form before every single scenario.

Is there a way to simply set up the session in this step without having to go through the form every single time?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the show as usual but this works for me on Rails 3.0.10.

In `features/support/authlogic.rb`:

```
require "authlogic/test_case"
World(Authlogic::TestCase)
ApplicationController.skip_before_filter :activate_authlogic
Before do
  activate_authlogic
end
```

Then in `features/step_definitions/user_sessions_steps.rb`

```
Given /^I am already logged in$/ do
  UserSession.create!(User.find_by_name!('user'))
end
```

Obviously, you can pass a username into the step definition if you want to login a specific user.

Full details are in this blog post: http://laserlemon.com/blog/2011/05/20/make-authlogic-and-cucumber-play-nice/

Comment: Dreadful. You should be going through the UI to do this, just like you should be going through the UI for virtually everything else in the integration tests—otherwise you're not really testing your application. Don't mess with app internals in your integration tests.

Comment: When you have thousands of cucumber scenarios you're adding a lot of overhead for little benefit. Be pragmatic about it.

Comment: I don't think it's pragmatic to have your integration tests violate the encapsulation of what they're supposed to test. That makes them unsafe and useless for their intended purpose. Better to write no tests at all than to write inaccurate ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Background in cucumber..ie

```
Background:
    Given I am a logged-in admin user
```

that will DRY up your scenarios.

http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/background

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually had that already, the problem was in the implementation of that step - physically having to go the form every time and fill in the page was slow, and a little unnecessary - I only need to test that once. In the end we solved this by stubbing the user session.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing a trick from another auth gem [Sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery)'s wiki: [Integration Testing with Rspec, Capybara and Fabricator](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/Integration-Testing-with-Rspec,-Capybara-and-Fabricator), they use:

```
page.driver.post(user_sessions_url, { username: user, password: password })
```

Which basically calls the `user_sessions_controller#create` method, so make sure the args match up. So for me, I did:

```
activate_authlogic
page.driver.post(user_sessions_url, { user_session: { email: user.email, password: user.password } })
```

I was searching for this for a few days. and `UserSession.create!` hadn't been able to work for me. Although this is an old question, I'm on Rails 4, hopefully it may help others stuck too.