# authlogic not working with capybara when using the selenium driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, authlogic, capybara

I have all my capybara tests working with my authlogic members area using the default driver, but when i change one test to use selenium driver as it has ajax in it, it gives my theis error :

```
You must activate the Authlogic::Session::Base.controller with a controller object before creating objects
```

Things are working with default driver for authlogic so must be something to do with selenium ??

I have include Authlogic::TestCase in my spec_helper and

```
activate_authlogic
    domain.user_sessions.create(user)
```

in a before each.

Any one help me with this please ?

thanks rick

Answer (score 5):

I posted a cucumber solution here: [Log-in through authlogic without having to fill in form every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629139/log-in-through-authlogic-without-having-to-fill-in-form-every-time/7927180#7927180)

For RSpec integration tests it's similar.

In your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require "authlogic/test_case"
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include Authlogic::TestCase
  ApplicationController.skip_before_filter :activate_authlogic
  config.before(:each, :type => :request) do
    activate_authlogic
    UserSession.create(User.find_by_email!(email))
  end
  ...
end
```

Obviously, if your site is not login only you may want to move the two lines in config.before into a before block in your specific test for logged in specs. If you leave as is you can delete the session with `UserSession.find.destroy` or obviously follow the logout link (if this makes more sense in your spec).

Answer (score 3):

I think the following code will work to activate authlogic:

```
Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self)
```

Having said that, I prefer defining a step that actually goes to the login form, fills it out, and logs in.  It's slower, but I rarely run my entire integration test suite manually, usually the continuous integration server takes care of that.

Comment: Yup. You *definitely* want your integration specs to actually use the login form. Oh, and scrap the integration specs -- use Cucumber instead; it's a lot nicer.

Comment: Cucumber is only useful if your customers are writing or at least reading the features (They should be of course). Otherwise you're just adding another layer.

Comment: I don't want to use the login form every time; only when actually testing the login form. Otherwise I'd rather not add extra time to my specs to complete a step that I already know works.

Comment: @PhilT Not true. Cucumber is useful whether or not your customers are reading the features (mine don't). The extra layer of abstraction is useful in preventing you from thinking like a programmer when you're testing UI. Every RSpec integration spec I've ever seen includes at least some "thinking like a programmer", because it's so tempting if you're writing in Ruby.

Comment: @Wheeyls Not testing things you know work is appropriate for unit testing. But for integration testing, the *point* is to test the entire application, end to end. As such, you shouldn't be mocking or bypassing anything (except external services).

Comment: Hi @MarnenLaibow-Koser. That's a pretty narrow definition of integration testing; I can think of plenty of situations where it's reasonable for an integration test to begin in a "logged in" state.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser yes you are right of course. That was written some time ago before everyone realised that we're all 'cuking it wrong'. Now we should be writing features with business language and letting the steps worry about the detail. But integration testing has it's place. Don't confuse integration testing with acceptance testing.

Comment: @Wheeyls Really? Like what? I can't think of any situation where the test shouldn't begin at a clean slate.

Comment: @PhilT Acceptance testing is a type of integration testing as far as I'm concerned. There are other types that are occasionally useful, but basically I care most about acceptance tests. Even unit testing is less important than acceptance testing IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me  (Rails 3.2.1) :

In **spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'authlogic/test_case' 
include Authlogic::TestCase
```

In **In my controller_specs :**

```
 def valid_session                                                                                                                                                                  
    activate_authlogic # run before tests are executed                                                                                                                               
    user = Factory(:user)                                                                                                                                                            
    UserSession.create(user, true) #create an authlogic session                                                                                                                      
    @user = @controller.current_user                                                                                                                                                 
    {}                                                                                                                                                                               
  end       
  # exemple of valid_session utilization in your test:
  #    valid_session
  #    user_id = @user.id
  #     
  #    or
  #
  #    get :index, {}, valid_session
```

Enjoy!